# Can we get the city and country of the current user from HTTP request?

Tags: html, location

Can we get the city and country name of the current user from **HTTP request headers**? As much as possible I don't want to use HTML5 geolocation, or the Google Map API.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the IP address from HTTP header. Then, you can lookup the IP address from a geolocation database.

There are a few free providers.

[IP2Location LITE](http://lite.ip2location.com)

[Maxmind GeoLite](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)

Alternative, you can use web API to query IP address.

[IPInfoDB](http://www.ipinfodb.com)

[IPInfo.io](http://IPInfo.io)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can. The IP address in the headers helps you to do that.

Check [Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/) or simply http://iplocation.net.

Edit - I should have said its not accurate. However the country data will be accurate in mostly all of the cases.

Comment: These services gives the ISP location, not the user's current location.